# FFmpeg: Splitting video into segments of very small size (e.g. 5KB)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to split a video file into segments that are less than 10KB (ideally 5KB) using FFmpeg.

The video I am using is this one: https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4. It already has a low resolution.

I have tried specifying a very small -segment_time of 00:00:0.04:

```
ffmpeg -i BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 00:00:0.04 BigBuckBunny_320x180_%03d.mp4
```

I have tried specifying sequential -segment_frames e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... etc.:

```
ffmpeg -i BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_frames 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 -segment_list out.csv BigBuckBunny_320x180_%03d.mp4
```

I have also tried to force key frames:

```
ffmpeg -i BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*0.04)" -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_frames 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 BigBuckBunny_320x180_%03d.mp4
```

All of these result in segments 0.5s long with varying file sizes averaging about 50KB.

```
username@My-Air:~/dev/video$ less out.csv 
BigBuckBunny_320x180_000.mp4,0.000000,0.500000
BigBuckBunny_320x180_001.mp4,0.500000,1.000000
BigBuckBunny_320x180_002.mp4,1.000000,1.500000
BigBuckBunny_320x180_003.mp4,1.500000,2.000000
BigBuckBunny_320x180_004.mp4,2.000000,2.500000
BigBuckBunny_320x180_005.mp4,2.500000,3.000000
...

username@My-Air:~/dev/video/bunny_0.5s_splits$ ls -l
total 134552
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    16K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_000.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    26K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_001.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    36K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_002.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    44K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_003.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    40K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_004.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    38K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_005.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    43K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_006.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    44K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_007.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    50K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_008.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    49K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_009.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    50K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_010.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    51K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_011.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    51K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_012.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    57K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_013.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    53K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_014.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    57K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_015.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    57K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_016.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    61K 25 Mar 23:40 BigBuckBunny_320x180_017.mp4
...
```

It's strange that the timestamps are at exactly 0s and 0.5s. Is this limitation of FFmpeg? I couldn't find any documentation to verify this.

Is there any way to get these file sizes down to 5KB? Is it possible with FFmpeg? If not, is there another tool I could use? I looked at GStreamer but couldn't really see if it was possible and it seems very complicated.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A single frame at 320x180 is 172K uncompressed. What makes you think that 5K is achievable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have compressed the file down (from 62MB to 22MB) using ffmpeg's default compression. But now when I try to split the compressed file into segments (using 00:00:01 as the `-segment_time`) it seems to make splits at random intervales. 10s, 1s, 3s, 7s, 10s etc. I get the same segments when I try and split at every frame (using `-segment-frames:1,2,3,4,5...`). What is the reason for this? Even after reading through the documentation I'm still a bit confused as to how FFmpeg is deciding these splits!

Comment: I would presume it's because of key frames, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about the process to be sure.

Comment: I forced every frame to be key a key frame and I managed to split the video then but only the first split worked. The rest of the splits were just a black video and no audio. I can split on every second frame using Movavi (which results in segments small enough in size) but I have to do it manually which isn't feasible for a long video. I'd like to know what software it's using under the covers so perhaps it can be done with a script or command?

Comment: I don't see how the goal is unachievable since it **has** been achieved. That quality of the video isn't the issue here. I needed small chunks to stream video across a future 5G network which is in testing stage and can't handle data >10KB. I know it's not a common use case but the commands below which show how to compress, set keyframes, and split video into segments could be useful to someone. They obviously don't need to adhere to the same extreme constraints as you put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I finally got what I wanted. I now have video segments all under 10KB averaging about 5KB. I used the following commands:

1. Compressed the original video file using ffmpeg's standard compression:

```
ffmpeg BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 BigBuckBunny_320x180_compressed.mp4
```

2. Set keyframe interval to 1 so every frame became a keyframe:

```
ffmpeg -i BigBuckBunny_320x180_compressed.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=1:scenecut=0 -acodec copy BigBuckBunny_320x180_compressed_frames.mp4
```

3. Split the resulting file into segments of length 0.04 which is about the length of one frame:

```
ffmpeg -i BigBuckBunny_320x180_compressed_frames.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:0.04 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 BigBuckBunny_320x180_compre
ssed_frames%03d.mp4
```

I resolved the previous issue where only the first segment was playing properly using: `-reset_timestamps 1`.